# Negative Inflation, AS/AD framework, What Graph to use?

Tags: macroeconomics

My macroeconomic homework contains the question below, and I'm not sure what graphs we're suppose to use to solve it. I believe I can answer the whole question using the IS-MP Diagram, but do I need another? Is the AS/AD question just referring to the changes in demand for funds when the new interest rate is applied in the IS-MP Diagram?

---

4. In the late 1990s and early 2000s, inflation was actually negative in Japan. I want you to consider a policy to achieve a higher inflation rate. Consider an economy that beings with output at potential and an inflation rate of ̅, so that the economy begins in steady state. A new chair of the central bank decides to raise the long-run inflation target to ̅2 (greater than the original ̅). Show how the economy responds over time using the AD/AS framework. Comment on your results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your teacher wants you to analyze the effects a higher inflation rate might have on the level of aggregate output based on whatever policy you might choose, i.e. drawing an AD/AS graph in long run equilibrium and demonstrating some shift as a result of the inflation-increasing policy.